# Android Studio: Why is 'languageLevel' different from 'JDK Location' value on new AS installation?

Tags: java, android-studio

In AndroidStudio I attempted to use a lambda expression, but I got the `Lambda expressions are not supported at this level` warning. But I am pretty sure that I have the java8 installed.

So I checked 2 places in Android Studio (which is all that I know to check):

**1 -** `.idea/misc.xml` ... ... I found: `<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_7" ...`

**2 -** `Project Structure/SDK Location/JDK Location` ... ... I found: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91`

Furthermore, if I go to `C:\Program Files\Java\`, I do not even have a '1.7.*' version available.

*(NOTE: If I hover over the lambda expression in my .java, it gives me an option `Set language level to 8`, which I will do.)*

But my question is: why were the two settings not sync'd?

Answer (score 2):

The language level and JDK are not one and the same. If you look at the [javac command line switches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) you will see that there are ones called `-source` and `-target`, which allow some limited cross-compilation between versions (so you could use a lower source level and emit class files that will run on an older JRE than your JVM). In this way, one can produce a library using their normal JDK, say 1.8.0_91, and that library can run on, say, 1.6.

By specifying the language level, you will thus cause IDEA to use various parameters to the compiler to do this sort of inter-version cross-compilation.

In fact, you will notice that there is a third setting in IDEA that specifies this behavior. Language level affects `-source`, the choice of JDK affects which JDK's compiler will be called (one clearly cannot compile `-source 1.8 -target 1.8` from a 1.5.0 JDK), and Settings->Build->Compiler->Java compiler->Project bytecode version presumably affects `-target`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that my Android Studio install is new ... I suppose that my question should be amended: "why does my new install assign different versions ..."

Answer (score 1):

Because you can compile for earlier versions of Java (the java compiler differentiates between source and target primarily for backwards compatibility reasons). This is actually fairly common among compilers (for example, `gcc` has flags for the desired C/C++ revision). However, because Java includes a virtual machine, it's also a kind of cross-compilation.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set JDK location to java 8 in under project structure -> SDK Location

Right now Android Studio 2.1 does not support lambda notation for java 8 but there is workaround for that.

You need to enable Jack compiler to support this feature
Add android { jackOptions { enabled true } } in build.gradle file
Also it would require Android Sdk Build-tools 24 or later. To download that open standalone SDK manager under sdk manager and download